# How does Alice kill the security guard just by looking at the security camera at the end of the Resident Evil Apocalypse?

Tags: resident-evil, resident-evil-apocalypse

At the end of the Resident Evil Apocalypse, how does Alice kill the security guard just by looking at the security camera?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The film's [official novelisation](http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/Resident_Evil:_Apocalypse_(novel)) indicates that she killed the guard (Daellanbach) using her psychic powers

> Down the hall, Alice knew — she wasn’t sure how, but she knew — that a guard named Daellanbach was watching her on a surveillance camera and screaming into a telephone.
>   “This is Central, request immediate backup, maximum response. Nemesis experiment is loose — repeat, Nemesis exp—”
>   **Alice wanted him to stop talking.
>
>   So he stopped,** falling to the ground, nose bleeding, screaming in agony as something sliced through his mind.

Comment: I think it was quite clear without the novelization too but anyway they never fully explained her super power too.

Comment: @AnkitSharma - That's true, but I had the novelisation open in front of me.